# Array won't output anything

Tags: c#

Doing a school activity but I hit a roadblock. I can't seem to make the program output the arrays I've entered. The output works when the variables inside the PlayerCharacter() and Mage() were all regular variables. Then I turned them into arrays because that was what was required of us, but then it started not showing anything during output.

```
using System;

namespace Summative
{

class PlayerCharacter
{
    string[] name = new string[10];
    int[] life = new int[10];
    char[] gender = new char[10];
    public int i = 0;
    public int x = 0;

    public PlayerCharacter()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter character name: ");
        this.Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter Life: ");
        this.Life = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter Gender (M/F): ");
        this.Gender = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        i++;

    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name[i];
        }
        set
        {
            name[i] = value;
        }
    }

    public int Life
    {
        get
        {
            return life[i];
        }
        set
        {
            life[i] = value;
        }
    }


    public char Gender
    {
        get
        {
            return gender[i];
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == 'M' || value == 'F')
            {
                gender[i] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Gender!");
            }
        }
    }

    public virtual void Output()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + string.Join(",", Name));
        Console.WriteLine("Life: " + string.Join(",", Life));
        Console.WriteLine("Gender: " + string.Join(",", Gender));
    }
}
class Mage : PlayerCharacter
{
    string[] element = new string[10];
    int[] mana = new int[10];
    public Mage() : base()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter element: ");
        this.Elements = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter mana: ");
        this.Mana = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public string Elements
    {
        get
        {
            return element[x];
        }
        set
        {
            element[x] = value;
        }
    }

    public int Mana
    {
        get
        {
            return mana[x];
        }
        set
        {
            mana[x] = value;
        }
    }

    public override void Output()
    {
        base.Output();
        Console.WriteLine("Element: " + string.Join(",", Elements));
        Console.WriteLine("Mana: " + string.Join(",", Mana));
        x++;
    }
}

class Rogue : PlayerCharacter
{
    string faction;
    float energy;

    public Rogue() : base()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter faction name: ");
        this.Faction = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter energy: ");
        this.Energy = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public string Faction
    {
        get
        {
            return faction;
        }
        set
        {
            faction = value;
        }
    }

    public float Energy
    {
        get
        {
            return energy;
        }
        set
        {
            energy = value;
        }
    }

    public override void Output()
    {
        base.Output();
        Console.WriteLine("Faction: " + Faction);
        Console.WriteLine("Energy: " + Energy);
    }
}

class Fighter : PlayerCharacter
{
    string weapon;
    double strength;

    public Fighter() : base()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter weapon name: ");
        this.Weapon = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter strength: ");
        this.Strength = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public string Weapon
    {
        get
        {
            return weapon;
        }
        set
        {
            weapon = value;
        }
    }

    public double Strength
    {
        get
        {
            return strength;
        }
        set
        {
            strength = value;
        }
    }

    public override void Output()
    {
        base.Output();
        Console.WriteLine("Weapon: " + Weapon);
        Console.WriteLine("Strength: " + Strength);
    }
}

class TestPlayer
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PlayerCharacter character;



    CharacterCreator:



        int switchchoice = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Select a class");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Mage");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Rogue");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Fighter");
            Console.WriteLine("0. Exit");
            Console.Write("Enter Choice: ");

            start:

            try
            {
                switchchoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input! Please Try Again.");
                goto CharacterCreator;
            }

            switch (switchchoice)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.Clear();
                    character = new Mage();
                    character.Output();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Console.Clear();
                    character = new Rogue();
                    character.Output();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    Console.Clear();
                    character = new Fighter();
                    character.Output();
                    break;

                case 0:
                    Console.Clear();
                    goto start;

                default:
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input! Please Try Again.");
                    goto CharacterCreator;
            }

        int choice;
        int y = 0;
        int z;
        int i = character.i;
        int x = character.x;

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Player Character Designer");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Create");
        Console.WriteLine("2. View");
        Console.Write("Enter Choice: ");
        choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());



        if (choice == 1)
        {
            goto CharacterCreator;
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            z = i;
            i = 0;
            x = 0;
            do
            {

                character.Output();
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                y++;
                i++;
                x++;
            } while (y != z);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: question: why does a single `PlayerCharacter` have 10 names, genders, and life-levels? shouldn't one suffice? should you perhaps have a `List<PlayerCharacter>` that represents multiple characters? but: during init, you read values into element `0`, then move `i` (the "which element am I reporting") to `1`. Element `1` is not initialized, so... (as a side note: reading from the console during a constructor makes me shudder with dread; it would be *much* preferable, IMO, to leave the console work in the `Program` code , and just set property values)

Comment: You didn't define a specific part in the array with `this.Name`. But like Marc suggest, you should use a List having multiple instances of `PlayerCharacter`.

Comment: I would recommend reducing your example to a more manageable size that illustrates the actual problem you are having. Also, using goto is generally frowned upon. But it is nice to mention that this is schoolwork.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer: Use a list

The main issue is that you should add the created characters in a list rather than keeping arrays of attributes *inside* characters. This lets you loop over each character and print all the information in turn. I.e.

```
var myCharacters = new List<PlayerCharacter>();
...
myCharacters.Add(myCharacter);
```

### Other Issues

##### Constructors & object design

Inject parameters in constructors whenever possible, and use auto-properties when applicable. This helps avoid complex logic in the constructors, and reduces the size of the classes. Let the creator of the characters be responsible for reading the necessary parameters. I would also prefer to separate the construction of the information-string and the output, that way you can output the same information to a log file or whatever, and not just to the console. I.e:

```
    class PlayerCharacter
    {
        public string Name { get; }
        public int Life { get; }
        public string Gender { get; }

        public PlayerCharacter(string name, int life, string gender)
        {
            Name = name;
            Life = life;
            Gender = gender;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Name: {Name}, Life {Life}, Gender: {Gender}";
        }
    }
```

##### Control flow

Use loops instead of goto. While I think there are cases where goto is the best solution, they are rare, and the general recommendation is to use loops for control flow i.e. something like this pseudocode

```
MyOptions option;
var myCharacters = new List<PlayerCharacter>();
do{
   myCharacters.Add(ReadCharacter());
   option = ReadOption();
}
while(option != MyOptions.ViewCharacters);
PrintCharacters(myCharacters);
```

##### Split code into methods

Move code into logical functions, especially for repeated code. This helps to make it easier to get a overview of the program. For example, for reading numbers it is better to use the `TryParse` function than trying to catch exceptions, and put it in a method to allow it to be reused:

```
int ReadInteger()
{
    int value;
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input! Please Try Again.");
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: A more complete answer could not be written. Still, I'd recommend separating the answer to the actual question from the other issues, so as to provide a clearer path for students.